# how to detect point inside polygon for neo4j, cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, point-in-polygon

I have node A with 2 properties lat, lon. **:A(lat : 11, lon : 12)**
and node B with 1 property polygon. **:B (polygon : [[10, 11], [5, 7], [1, 2], ....]).** how can I detect is A inside list point of polygon which is property of B??

Answer (score 1):

Right now exists the "spatial-algorithms" library which, among other things, supports the recent geometry point specification "Point". Although there is a [presentation](https://neo4j.com/blog/building-spatial-search-algorithms-neo4j/)  that explains how this library works, I have not been able to find a manual on how to use it, however, following the simple steps of installing the library that we can find in the [Github project](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial-algorithms), and reviewing the tests of the same project, it does not work very difficult to use it.

Specifically, to check that a point is inside a polygon we must do:

1.First we create the polygon with an array of geometric points belongs to node "place", in this case a triangle.

```
WITH
  point({x: 0, y: 0}) AS p1,
  point({x: 3, y: 3}) AS p2,
  point({x: 6, y: 0}) AS p3
CREATE (n:Place{polygon:[p1,p2,p3]}) return n
```

2.We define this array as a polygon with the function "spatial.polygon".

3.And next we check that the point p1 is inside the polygon with the function "spatial.algo.withinPolygon"

```
MATCH (place) where ID(place)=290416
WITH
  point({x: 3, y:10}) AS p1, place,
 spatial.polygon(place.polygon) AS polygon RETURN spatial.algo.withinPolygon(p1,polygon)
```

You can see more information, such as geometric data indexing, [here](https://community.neo4j.com/t5/integrations/using-polygon-areas-in-bounding-box-query/m-p/46956).

Answer (score -1):

[Neo4j spatial](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial) has support for this, be sure to read its user manual.